# HTML parece não reconhecer flask

Tags: html, python, flask

sou um iniciante tentando aprender a trabalhar com flask
segui alguns tutoriais e vi a documentação, mas ainda não entendo o que fiz de errado
o programa era pra simplesmente mostrar o nome que estivesse na variável, só que no template em html

eis respectivamente os códigos em python e html
o resto do html parece funcionar bem, então acho que é apenas algum detalhe mínimo, mas não vejo o que

```
t="teste"
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', t=t)
```

```
<body>
<h1>Teste1.0</h1>
    
{{ t }}


</body>
```

Comment: O seu `index.html` precisa ficar dentro de um diretorio chamado `templates`

Comment: Como estão organizados os arquivos do seu app? Talvez o flask não esteja encontrando o `index.html`, pois ele deve ficar dentro do diretório `templates`
exemplo: ├ templates/ │ └ index.html ├ app.py

Comment: o '.html' está sim dentro de 'templates', e o app.py fora. não parece ser esse o problema...

Answer (score 0):

Olá vou colocar um exemplo simples que eu fiz, confere suas estrutura das pastas, o nome dos arquivos, o espaçamento das chaves no html:

Conteúdo do arquivo python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template 

text_to_tile = 'Texto para o título'

#Cria aplicação flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def show_template():
    #title é o texto substituido no html
    return  render_template('index.html', title=text_to_tile)

#inicia a aplicação
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

Conteúdo do index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        Conteúdo do título <h1 id='title_id'>{{ title }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Conteúdo do pasta:

[image: Estrtutura da pasta]